# Can I override org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

**Overriding the default logger in mule so that I have some custom details to be sent to the logger threadcontext every time before the log message is print. Especially before the default payloads are print.**

Answer (score 0):

You should not override the Mule API package. Also if this is for Mule 4 -the version wasn't mentioned- you have to be aware that the threading model will probably not allow you to reuse the thread context. Potentially each message processor can execute in a separate thread.

As an alternative, I have seen people implementing their own logging connectors/modules to customize logging operation.

Comment: how you do this? that would really solve the puzzle

Comment: Just follow the instructions in the documentation to create a module: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/getting-started, then replace the operations by your own.

Answer (score 0):

**Thumbrule - This class cannot be overridden**

So probably we can have a custom transformer that initialises the thread context so that in a specific flow in mule, the successive flows will follow the rountine of that thread context with value set since a flow is considered as THREAD.

If you want to do this in a more enhanced way - We can go for creating Message Processor. Please refer to the link below:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/connector-devkit/3.9/creating-message-processors